# FTP errors due to extra slash in home path

Tags: ftp

We started recently getting errors with one provider due to an extra slash in the home path:

/home/userdir//public_html

(Yes, the provider is cPanel based server unfortunately)

While FTP desktop software doesn't seem to mind, our site deployment system uses scripted FTP and minds very much.

Is this an indication the provider has symlinked or hardlinked the user homes?

Comment: So fix your broken script?  A double slash in a posix file path is perfectly valid and treated exactly the same as a single slash.

Comment: I tend to agree, I think this issue will happen again. However, we work with thousands of hosting companies and this issue is only occurring at 1 of them to date. At this time, the money to have our development team re-write the FTP client section of our software is not justified by the issue. If it begins to happen with more providers that may change, of course.

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the answer likely to be simpler that that? I'd assume that the home directory for that user has been defined as /home/userdir/ in /etc/passwd (or the equivalent database) instead of /home/userdir

Comment: We have asked them to check this and also the FTP home settings in the FTP daemon. No response so far.